Finding subset with max/min set bits under XOR
I have a set of N numbers (N is comparatively small, <100), with each with B bits (B is very large, in the millions at least). I want to find the non-empty subset of numbers which when XOR'd together, produce an integer of B bits with the maximum number of bits set 1, and similarly also find the (non-empty) subset with the minimum.
Just to be completely clear, lets go through a simple example. Say we have a set of N=3 numbers with B=64 bits, written in binary:
A := 0111000010111000110011011110101100100001000011110100001111000100  (30 bits set)
B := 1011100011010110000100111101100011010100110000110101100111011110  (34 bits set)
C := 0011111110111010011101001111000010101110111110101000100011010011  (37 bits set)

Here's the potential XOR-sums between these:
A^B   := 1100100001101110110111100011001111110101110011000001101000011010  (34 bits set)
A^C   := 0100111100000010101110010001101110001111111101011100101100010111  (35 bits set)
B^C   := 1000011101101100011001110010100001111010001110011101000100001101  (31 bits set)
A^B^C := 1111011111010100101010101100001101011011001101101001001011001001  (35 bits set)

In this case, the max number of bits set happened to come from the subset {C}, with its 37 set bits. The min also happened to be a subset of just one element, {A}, with 30 bits set. The next smallest would be {B, C} with 31 bits set, which would have been the min had A had more bits set.
The naive brute-force approach would be to just iterate though the 2^N - 1 combinations of numbers, XOR each with O(B*N) primitive operations, count the bits set, and update a global max/min accordingly. I could cache intermediate results to remove that factor of N, but it would still involve O(2^N * B) operations, which isn't tractable for my ranges of N and B above.
My first thought was to go with a meet-in-the-middle approach, in a similar spirit to the subset sum problem.  I could compute 2^(N/2) intermediate XOR-sums from each half of the set of numbers, then iterate though value in one of the halves and do some high-dimensional nearest-neighbor search for a close match (or a close-match to its 1s complement).
Barring the feasibility and time implications of the nearest neighbor search, it'd result in a reduction to O(2^(N/2) * B) operations, which still isn't very tractable.
My next thought was to potentially use gaussian elimination / reduced row echelon form to find any linear dependence between these numbers (treated as vectors of 0s and 1s).  Problem is that for just N (small) vectors of B (large) elements, I'm unlikely to find two linearly dependent vectors (which I could then combine to get a XOR-sum with all 0s). I'll note that if I magically knew what the maximum (or minimum) XOR-sum value was, I could use this approach to discover the vectors that produced that XOR-sum.
I'm now out of ideas, and I'm hoping that someone else may have some different ideas about how to approach this problem. If it comes down to it, I could settle for an approximation rather than the optimal min/max subset, if the approximation is very close (in terms of percentage of bits set in the XOR) to that of the real min/max subset.
I want to offer one small insight I had, which I wasn't able to make use of but maybe someone else can.  For a subset of an even count of numbers, you can take the one's complement of the set of numbers and arrive at an equivalent (bit flipped) subset, which produces the exact same XOR-sum (because we're flipping each bit an even number of times. For a subset of an odd count of numbers, the same subset (flipped) would flip the bits of the XOR-sum, converting it from a max solution to a potential min solution (or vice versa).
This means if we find an algorithm for exclusively the max case (or exclusively min), we can transform it into a solution for the other, depending on the parity of the subset size. If the true min solution is odd (we don't necessarily know yet), we can just flip the bits and search for the new max solution. If its really even, we guess one of the numbers in the subset, and search for a new max solution for the remaining (odd count) numbers, repeating for all N possible guesses, and taking the min of the candidate solutions. We then take the min of the odd / even candidates, for the true min solution.

What's the motivation for this question? Is it a coding challenge? What makes you believe solving it optimally is tractable for N up to 100?

This sounds like a perfect problem for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality to be an issue. In which case I doubt that any good algorithm exists. I have no idea what your motivation is, but if B is in the millions, then my expectation for the difference between the most bits set to 1 and the fewest is, on average, just a few percent.

@SimonGoater this is not a coding challenge, and I don't know that it necessarily even is tractable. I see similarities to other well-studied problems like the subset sum problem for instance. I don't have any strong evidence to support that there can't be a faster algorithm, which gives me hope.

@btilly This problem spawns from trying to create a poor linear approximation of a very non-linear (practically random) discrete piece-wise function on the bit-level. If each vector of B bits were a row in matrix, each column would be some bits of the input and output of said function, so finding a subset of columns that XOR with some bias towards 0s or 1s would give me a (poor) linear approximation in the bits of the input. As you say, the difference is probably going to be less than a percent, but I'll even take that in some cases.

One thought I had was to just calculate as many combinations as you can in whatever time you have, and take the max/min popcounts. You could order the combinations in increasing order of included numbers from 1 to N to get through more than just random which would have on average N/2 numbers to XOR. A GPU would probably be good for this, even though it's highly likely to be memory bound.

Just to state this problem more compactly, you have a B-dimensional vector space V over GF(2) generated by your N vectors, and you are seeking the minimum and maximum hamming weight elements of V.

I am not sure about higher combinations, but for combination of xor of dimension two, you can eliminate few by maximum 1's=n-(a+b)%n,minimum 1's=
n-min(a,b), so you dont have to do xor,if you have number of 1's in every number of N saved which is a,b,c.. and n is number of bits, then using above you can pre eliminate those whose max one is less that previous founded answer, as for higher dimension like a^b^c you can use max,min 1 of a^b as input in x^c, they wont eliminate much,just an idea
